# Error in Jazzcash integration with flutter. Every transaction failed with error code 119

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform, payment-gateway, payment

{"pp_Amount":"4222","pp_AuthCode":"","pp_BankID":"","pp_BillReference":"billRef","pp_Language":"EN","pp_MerchantID":"My ID","pp_ResponseCode":"199","pp_ResponseMessage":***"Sorry! Your transaction was not successful. Please try again later.***","pp_RetreivalReferenceNo":"230221337471","pp_SubMerchantId":"","pp_TxnCurrency":"PKR","pp_TxnDateTime":"20230221154200","pp_TxnRefNo":"T20230221154200","pp_SettlementExpiry":"","pp_TxnType":"MWALLET","pp_Version":"1.1","ppmpf_1":"030844#####","ppmpf_2":"","ppmpf_3":"","ppmpf_4":"","ppmpf_5":"","pp_SecureHash":"EECFF4DA57C8B3BDC741461B5D0C4BA73082C9A2A0F5078E727DDAE2864B7065"}

I Don't know what is issue in my code I've used this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199463/how-to-connect-easypaisa-jazzcash-payment-gateway-in-flutter)

My Code is

```
`import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as  http;
import 'package:improvement/citizen_portal/colors.dart';
import 'package:improvement/citizen_portal/widgets/button.dart';

class JazzCashIntegration extends StatefulWidget {
  const JazzCashIntegration({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<JazzCashIntegration> createState() => _JazzCashIntegrationState();
}

class _JazzCashIntegrationState extends State<JazzCashIntegration> {
  TextEditingController amountCtrl = TextEditingController();
  bool hasnotAmount = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(child: Text('Jazz Cash Testing')),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Please Enter Amount:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: MyColors.appText,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: amountCtrl,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  filled: true,
                  isDense: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      borderSide: BorderSide.none),
                  fillColor: MyColors.appWhiteShade,
                  labelText: 'Enter Amount',
                  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
                  errorText: !hasnotAmount ? 'Please Enter amount': null,
                ),
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    setState(() {
                      hasnotAmount  =  true;
                    });
                  }
                  else{
                    setState(() {
                      hasnotAmount  =  false;
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    payment();
                  },
                  child: const RoundBtn(txt: 'Confirm', hasIcon: false))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  payment() async{
    var digest;
    String dateandtime = DateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(DateTime.now());
    String dexpiredate = DateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)));
    String tre = "T"+dateandtime;
    String pp_Amount=
    amountCtrl.text.trim().toString();
    String pp_BillReference="billRef";
    String pp_Description="Description";
    String pp_Language="EN";
    String pp_MerchantID= "My Merchant ID";
    String pp_Password="My Password";

    String pp_ReturnURL="https://sandbox.jazzcash.com.pk/ApplicationAPI/API/Payment/DoTransaction";
    String pp_ver = "1.1";
    String pp_TxnCurrency= "PKR";
    String pp_TxnDateTime=dateandtime.toString();
    String pp_TxnExpiryDateTime=dexpiredate.toString();
    String pp_TxnRefNo=tre.toString();
    String pp_TxnType="MWALLET";
    String ppmpf_1="030844#####";
    String IntegeritySalt = "My Salt";
    String and = '&';
    String superdata=
        IntegeritySalt+and+
            pp_Amount+and+
            pp_BillReference +and+
            pp_Description +and+
            pp_Language +and+
            pp_MerchantID +and+
            pp_Password +and+
            pp_ReturnURL +and+
            pp_TxnCurrency+and+
            pp_TxnDateTime +and+
            pp_TxnExpiryDateTime +and+
            pp_TxnRefNo+and+
            pp_TxnType+and+
            pp_ver+and+
            ppmpf_1
    ;



    var key = utf8.encode(IntegeritySalt);
    var bytes = utf8.encode(superdata);
    var hmacSha256 = Hmac(sha256, key);
    Digest sha256Result = hmacSha256.convert(bytes);
    var url = 'https://sandbox.jazzcash.com.pk/ApplicationAPI/API/Payment/DoTransaction';

    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "pp_Version": pp_ver,
      "pp_TxnType": pp_TxnType,
      "pp_Language": pp_Language,
      "pp_MerchantID": pp_MerchantID,
      "pp_Password": pp_Password,
      "pp_TxnRefNo": tre,
      "pp_Amount": pp_Amount,
      "pp_TxnCurrency": pp_TxnCurrency,
      "pp_TxnDateTime": dateandtime,
      "pp_BillReference": pp_BillReference,
      "pp_Description": pp_Description,
      "pp_TxnExpiryDateTime":dexpiredate,
      "pp_ReturnURL": pp_ReturnURL,
      "pp_SecureHash": sha256Result.toString(),
      "ppmpf_1":ppmpf_1
    });
    print(response.statusCode.toString());
    print("response=>");
    print(response.body);
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? I also keep on getting 199 error